# Windows 7 profile is always switching to temp profile even though logged in as Administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am having a weird problem with my windows 7. Whenever I reboot and login it is switching to temporary profile. It is kind of annoying as this behavior is happening 8 out 10 times.

I googled and followed the instructions from the forum post, but still no luck.

Instructions I followed from these links ( i double checked the procedure multiple times):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/5ec0b949-effa-4e30-ba09-dc948a4c7a8b

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/221736-windows-7-x64-you-have-been-logged-on-with-a-temorary-profile

OS: Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Did you install any software prior to this behavior?

Comment: I guess Google Picasso desktop software.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you just change yourself as super admin.
Run cmd as adminstrator

At the prompt type:
net user administrator /active:yes
Now press Enter
You should now see “The command completed successfully”.
Now log out of your regular account and you will see “Administrator” as an option on the login screen,
At this point, please set a password for this new account. And remember, do not use this account for everyday computing.
Should you ever wish to disable the Super Administrator account, just open command prompt again (Run as administrator).
And at the prompt type:
net user administrator /active:no
Press Enter

Its worked when tried .. tryout